# How can I switch back from Google Chrome making itself my default image viewer?

Tags: image-viewers

I downloaded and installed the latest Google Chrome browser (BTW not out of choice) and now for some reason it has set itself as my default image viewer. How do I reverse this so that my original image viewer is the default?

I'm using Ubuntu version 20.04.2 LTS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File associations are controlled using the file manager Files. Change the default association of a type of files, e.g. `png` files, by right-clicking any `.png` file. Right-click and select "Properties". Set the default application using the "Open with" tab.

Comment: Thanks. This is something I didn't know which will be useful.